# Migration from ionic beta 13 to beta 14

Tags: ionic-framework

What are the best possible ways to migrate my project developed in ionic beta 13 version to the latest release of ionic beta 14?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to review the changelog of ionic https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md and the migration guide from AngularJS 1.2 to 1.3 (since the underlying AngularJS version was bumped with beta14 of ionic).

The Angular migration guide is located here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration

Comment: lib folder contains all the library related files. So i replaced the old lib folder with new one.

Answer (score 0):

For most projects, the two commands that you'd want to use to get Ionic up to date are:

First, make sure your CLI is up to date:

```
sudo npm install -g ionic
```

Second, update the project libraries:

```
ionic lib update
```

For advanced users, the links shared in other answers will be of great help.